# How do spacecraft cameras work?

Tags: space

When I look at pictures taken by a modern spacecraft (like that one showing the surface of Titan:

[image: Titan]

and taken by [Cassini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens)) I kinda understand how they might be produced. There might be some kind of CCD sensor installed and the data is later transmitted to Earth.

But then I think about it I start to wonder how cameras worked on older spacecrafts like [Mariner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_program), for example this one taken by [Viking 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_1)

[image: Mars].

As far as I know there were no digital cameras back then. How did they get around it and were able to produce photos and more importantly sent imaging data back to Earth?

I can imagine that there was an analog camera installed along with some scanning facility but that sounds *sooo* unlikely as it would require a rather complex machinery which isn't feasible for an operation in space. But other than that I'm out of ideas. Wikipedia is surprisingly silent about it, too.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks, everybody, for your great answers! I upvoted everything I could and accepted [Georg](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1370/georg)'s answer for a great Wiki link.

Comment: What kind of camera do You think was used for TV in 1936 Olympics or when the lift of of Apollo spaceships was on TV?

Comment: http://www.telefunken.com/company/history/1923-1936/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a lot of (TV) Cameras from the first [Ikonoskops](http://www.oebl.de/Fernseh/Kamera/index.html) 
(by Zworykin) in the 30ties up to Orthicons or Plumbicons and what [-cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_camera_tube) ever 
were invented.  Just google for that names.

PS The word "digital" is misused a lot today. The CCDs 
are not digital, there is some analog/digital stage coupled to the CCD or 
maybe "onboard" the CCD chip. But nevertheless the CCD works 
analog.

Comment: Well they are digital upto the output amp (1 photon = 1 electron) and with science CCD cameras you have readout noise of 1 electron so digital-ish

Comment: @Martin, then read about working principle of all those -trons. Most (All?) of them were digital-ish from beginning by Your definition. (1 photon = 1 electron)

Comment: that was interesting I didn't realise that Vidicons actualy stored an image - I thought it was purely a scanned photo-conductor thing. And that the predecessors to vidicons were a lot like the intensified - Image Photon Counting Systems that competed with CCDS when I started doing astronomy cameras

Comment: @Martin, You need either the charge accumulation or some really high amplification as in a photomultiplier. The latter did not exist in the thirties and more important: optical scanning is mechanical demanding, heavy and voluminous. The ony exception I know were those tubes with a electron picture, amplified in channel array plates, then directed on a phosphor for direct wieving. (used in night vision equipment)

Comment: I knew they were electronically scanned, I just thought the e-beam measured the conductivity of the photocathode at each  point at that time - ie the cathode was only biased at the point the beam was scanning . I didn't appreciate that there was an actual charge image on the plate.

Answer (score 2):

Viking1 used [vidicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidicon#Vidicon) basically the same thing that studio TV cameras used into the 80s

Answer (score 1):

Others answered about the old cameras, but a piece of trivia about current space craft cameras to clarify a small misconception: the primary cameras used in the Mars landers (like Spirit and Opportunity) are high-resolution B&W cameras equipped with switchable color filters for R, G and B. The craft sends 3 b&w images filtered through the 3 filters and they only get composed into one color image by earth crew.

Comment: Is this still done in that way? Separate filters can have a much higher quality compared to the "dots" on a CCD. So for stills this technology is perfered still today?

Comment: In science cameras yes - large multilayer filters a re much better than the colored dyes on a bayer mask and you can have as many bands as you want. And for commercial large format digital , at least for still life - you get the full image resolution for each color and no moire effects

Comment: The [primary cameras on MSL](http://msl-scicorner.jpl.nasa.gov/Instruments/Mastcam/) (Curiosity) are "full colour" and use RGB Bayer pattern filters like those on Earthbound consumer digital cameras (though there is an array of additional filters available).